# How to get student maximum interm marks

Tags: sql-server

i want to get maximum student interm marks from below table.

```
Student name    Interm1 marks    Interm2 marks     Interm3 marks
Raj             60               75                89
raju            78               74                67
ram             67               79                65
balaji          91               89                93
```

My required Output is:

```
Balaji 93
```

option:

```
raju 78
raj 89 etc..
```

like this i need output.
 can any body help me here for this query.

Comment: Have you tried using `GROUP BY` combined with `MAX` aggregation?

Comment: You'll need to unpivot the data too, @schlonzo .

Comment: Oh, now that the code is better readable I see that problem

Comment: This question should help - [Does SQL Server support GREATEST and LEAST, if not what is the common workaround?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187095/7257).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to first unpivot your data, and then get the `MAX` value. I prefer using `VALUES` to unpivot data, rather than the `UNPIVOT` operator:

```
SELECT YT.StudentName,
       MAX(IM.ItermMark) AS MaxItermMark
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(Interm1Mark),(Interm2Mark),(Interm3Nark))IM(ItermMark)
GROUP BY StudentName;
```

Comment: StudentName MaxItermMark
Balaji 91
kumar 85
prem 92
Raja 93
Raju 91
Ram 94
Dear Larnu now i am getting out put each student name wise . How can i get only one student name from above data like Ram 94 only.  Thanks for your support.

Comment: I have used below query to get only one high record.     I got required output.                                     
 with ctevalues  as (
sELECT  YT.StudentName,
       MAX(IM.ItermMark) AS MaxItermMark,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by  MAX(IM.ItermMark) desc) as rowno
FROM Student YT
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(Interm1),(Interm2),(Interm3))IM(ItermMark)
GROUP BY StudentName)

select * from ctevalues

where rowno=1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this. This should do what you want to do

```
SELECT [Student name], MAX(MaxMark)
FROM
(
    SELECT [Student name], 
        (SELECT MAX(v) FROM (VALUES ([Interm1 marks]), ([Interm2 marks]), ([Interm3 marks])) AS value(v)
     ) AS [MaxMark]
) AS subquery
GROUP BY [Student name]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response